# HTML convert time value to proper formatting when pre-populating input field

Tags: html, django, forms

I am trying to pre-populate a **time** field on an input form, and I'm getting the field from a database. I was successful in finding how to do this with the date field by putting this in my value attribute:

```
"value="{{shipment.pickup_date|date:'Y-m-d'}}">"
```

Is there a similar conversion I can make with a time value? I've tried "HH:mm:ss", "H:m:s", to no avail. I can see in via the Chrome Elements tab that the value is getting passed properly, it's just not getting displayed in the field.

[image]

Comment: Try the `time` filter with format `H:i`: `<input type="time" name="pickup_time" value="{{ shipment.pickup_date|time:'H:i' }}">`. This assumes that `pickup_date` is a `datetime` object.

Comment: my pickup_time field is actually a TimeField in my model. Does this change things?

Comment: It shouldn't. Give it a try, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a value to the `input` tag in your template by passing the shipment's `pickup_date` value to the [`time` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#time) with the right format. Providing the right format is key here, since the additional `a.m.` in your current value is not accepted. As a result, `type="time"` expects something like `H:M`; where `H` is the hour in double digits, and `M` is the minutes in double digits, as well. This means that you should change your code to the following:

```
<div class="">
  <input type="time" name="pickup_time" value="{{ shipment.pickup_date|time:'H:i' }}">
</div>
```

Here, `H:i` is the format that converts your time value to something like `H:M`.